# DateTimePicker MUI displays not the passed value but wrong value with timezone React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I am passing a value to the DateTimePicker component from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker' but the displayed value is different from the passed one. It displays +2 hours or sometimes +1 hour (I guess is something to do with timezone)

Example:
The value being passed : 'Mon Sep 26 2022 11:54:22 GMT+0000' (formikField.value)

What is displayed: [image]

```
                  <DateTimePicker
                        label={label}
                        value={formikField.value}
                        disabled={disabled}
                        onChange={(newValue) => {
                            helpers.setValue(newValue);
                        }}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField {...params} {...field} fullWidth error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)} helperText={meta.error} />
                        )}
                        minDate={props.minDate ?? null}
                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

As sated in the MUI Pro documentation you need to wrap your date picker component inside a localization provider. You need to pick a provider to use and pass it as props into the localization provider.

You can read more about it here: [MUI datepicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/)

code snippet from their examples:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import updateLocale from "dayjs/plugin/updateLocale";
import nl from "dayjs/locale/nl";
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DateTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker';
dayjs.extend(updateLocale);
dayjs.updateLocale("nl", { weekStart: 0 });
dayjs.locale("nl");

export default function BasicDateTimePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(dayjs());

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider locale={nl} dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DateTimePicker
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
        label="DateTimePicker"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have wrapped it inside localization provider and also using as a dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}.

Comment: I edited the code snippet to show how I got rid of the date time picker using the incorrect time. You need to pass in your local locale as far as I know